# Kotlin: RestTemplateCustomizer customize() method is not being called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate

- I am writing a customize ResponseErrorHandler for all RestTemplate api call in application. This application is a Spring Boot application and written in Kotlin

My code:

ServiceApiErrorHandler.class

```
class ServiceApiErrorHandler(
    @Autowired
    val agentAuthService: AgentAuthService
) : DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
    companion object {
        private val logger: LogService = LogServiceImpl(ServiceApiErrorHandler::class.java)
    }

    override fun hasError(response: ClientHttpResponse): Boolean {
        return (response.statusCode.is4xxClientError || response.statusCode.is5xxServerError)
    }

    override fun handleError(response: ClientHttpResponse) {
        logger.info("LOGIN AGAIN 1")

    }

    override fun handleError(url: URI, method: HttpMethod, response: ClientHttpResponse) {
        if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED && ServiceApiEnpoint.isServiceApiEndpoint(url = url.toString())) {
            logger.info("LOGIN AGAIN")
            agentAuthService.callLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomRestTemplateCustomizer class

```
class CustomRestTemplateCustomizer(
    @Autowired
    val agentAuthService: AgentAuthService
) : RestTemplateCustomizer {
    override fun customize(restTemplate: RestTemplate) {
            restTemplate.errorHandler = ServiceApiErrorHandler(agentAuthService = agentAuthService)
    }
}
```

ClientHttpConfig class

```
@Configuration
class ClientHttpConfig(
    @Autowired
    val agentAuthService: AgentAuthService
) {
    @Bean
    fun customRestTemplateCustomizer(): CustomRestTemplateCustomizer {
        return CustomRestTemplateCustomizer(agentAuthService = agentAuthService);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run, RestTemplate still handle error using DefaultResponseErrorHandler and after debug, I quickly realize that **the customize() method in class CustomRestTemplateCustomizer was never being called.**

So my questions is:

- Is customize() method suppose to be automatic called? If not, how should i call it?
- Does my code is ok to implement customize ResponseErrorHandler?

Note: I follow the tutorial in Java: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder to write this version in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you create the RestTemplate instance?

try adding a Bean, then the customizer should be used

```
@Configuration
class ClientHttpConfig(
    @Autowired
    val agentAuthService: AgentAuthService,
    @Autowired val builder: RestTemplateBuilder
) {
    @Bean
    fun customRestTemplateCustomizer(): CustomRestTemplateCustomizer {
        return CustomRestTemplateCustomizer(agentAuthService = agentAuthService);
    }

    @Bean
    fun customizedRestTemplate(): RestTemplate {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Edit: needs to be created by RestTemplateBuilder

Comment: This is not answer my question :( When debug, i have already try like you suggest and everything work fine with just MposApiErrorHandler.class, no need for other class. But **the main reason i create these customize class is it can configure for all RestTemplate API call in the whole application**.

Comment: customize is called by RestTemplateBuilder to create a RestTemplate, so it won't work this way if you create other RestTemplate instances on your own

Comment: In this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder, section 3, it suggest that **it is the way to have every RestTemplate that used in application will have the custom errorHandler set on it** in Java. So do you think i have misunderstand something here or it just not work the same in Kotlin?

Comment: it's the same in Java, if you create a RestTemplate using new it doesn't use the customizer... The tutorial is wrong in this part or simply missing the hint to create it by RestTemplateBuilder

Comment: Can you eddit your answer to be more specific?  I don't know which class i should modify and how can i do it.

Comment: just define a bean in a configuration class and inject the created RestTemplate instance in the class you want to use it. Or inject the RestTemplateBuilder and use build()